# How To Exclude a specific rule from a specific file in Sonarlint

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I am trying to exclude a specific rule from a file in sonarlint, I have multiple java automation projects open in eclipse, and I am wondering if my "Value" is correct on my analyzed property that I have set. (LN_LexisConveyOnline is the name of the project)
I have implemented the below, and nothing seems to change. Thanks

[My Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEwcl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a Java file, you might want to opt for `@SuppressWarnings("java:S100")` instead or `//NOSONAR`.

Note that SonarLint (the Eclipse plugin) and Sonar (the server) may not share the same key for the same rule. I had at least the problem with issue prefixed by `java:` and `squid:` (I presumed this was the old prefix).

Answer (score 0):

You can do right click over rule, and click in Exclude rule. This, in the browser of rules in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Hi Jhon, This excludes the rule for all files, i am wanting to exclude for a specific file only. 

Thanks though.